# Spark Session returned an error : Apache NiFi

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-nifi, livy

We are trying to run a spark program using NiFi. [This is the basic sample](https://medium.com/@evanescence1106/in-this-article-we-will-use-apache-nifi-to-schedule-batch-jobs-in-spark-cluster-abb41d112042) we tried to follow.

We have configured Apache-Livy server in `127.0.0.1:8998`.

`ExecutiveSparkInteractive` processor is used to run sample Spark code.

```
val gdpDF = spark.read.json("gdp.json")
val gdpRDD = gdpDF.rdd
gdpRDD.count()
```

`LivyController` is confiured for `127.0.0.1` port `8998` and `Session Type : spark`.

When we run the processor we get following error :

> Spark Session returned an error, sending the output JSON object as the flow file content to failure (after penalizing)

We just want to output the line count in JSON file. How to redirect it to flowfile?

NiFi User log :

> 2020-04-13 21:50:49,955 INFO [NiFi Web Server-85]
>   org.apache.nifi.web.filter.RequestLogger Attempting request for
>   (anonymous) GET
>   http://localhost:9090/nifi-api/flow/controller/bulletins (source ip:
>   127.0.0.1)

NiFi app.log

> ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3]
>   o.a.n.p.livy.ExecuteSparkInteractive
>   ExecuteSparkInteractive[id=9a338053-0173-1000-fbe9-e613558ad33b] Spark
>   Session returned an error, sending the output JSON object as the flow
>   file content to failure (after penalizing)

Comment: did you have more log in nifi-app.log ?

Comment: experiencing same error

Comment: I found more information in the logs

Comment: @Bob really, could you please post them here?

Comment: For future reference: this was also asked on the Cloudera Community: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Spark-Session-returned-an-error/m-p/293348/highlight/false#M216650

Answer (score 1):

I have seen several people struggling with this example. I recommend following this example from the Cloudera Community (especially note part 2).
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/HDF-3-1-Executing-Apache-Spark-via-ExecuteSparkInteractive/ta-p/247772

The key points I would be concerned with:

1. Does your spark work in general
2. Does your livy work in general
3. Is the Spark sample code good